# Any issues running 20.04 with a Ryzen 5000 CPU?

Tags: 20.04, cpu

I'm thinking about building a new computer.  Would like to get a Ryzen 5000 series CPU (if I can find one.)  I know support for the 5000 series was added to a later linux kernel than is included with 20.04.  Has anyone tried to run 20.04 on a Ryzen 5000?  Any major issues?  I am aware the temperature sensors will not work which is fine, but is there anything else I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

I had many issues in my laptop which is Acer Aspire A7 with AMD Ryzen 5500U and NVIDIA GTX 1650.
After installation (dual boot) of Ubuntu, it won't boot up.

If you have installed NVIDIA Driver , remove them and follow the below steps.
In-order to fix that you have to add `nomodeset` parameter in the grub only once.
Once that is added you will be able boot into Ubuntu and login.

Next the Brightness functionality was not working , also once the NVIDIA driver (460) is installed Ubuntu won't boot up at freezes at a cursor blinking.

After spending few weeks going through the NVIDIA and Ask-Ubuntu forums , I came to know there is specific problem in Linux Kernel support for AMD Ubuntu support.

This is how I solved:
After login into Ubuntu using `nomodest` parameter

Ubuntu 20.04 has kernel of 5.8 , AMD 5000 series requires 5.10+ kernel version , in-order to upgrade this follow:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

After this

- open mainline application , by typing `mainline` in terminal.
- Select latest kernel available and install.
- remove the `nomodeset` parameter from grub, don't forget to do `sudo update-grub`, if you did this in `/etc/default/grub`, then reboot
- Make sure to disable secure boot option in BIOS
- Select the latest ubuntu kernel and login

Next we need to fix the AMD firmware to fix brightness control.The GPU of the 5xxx series will be called Cezanne, a descendant of the 4xxx Renoir GPU. Currently, it has the codename “Green Sardine” so the driver tries to load green_sardine firmware.

Now after login navigate to [https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/gs/](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Eagd5f/radeon_ucode/gs/)

- Download all of them and copy to `/lib/firmware/amdgpu`
- Then in terminal type `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Reboot
- Now the brightness functionality should be working, now you can install NVIDIA graphics
- Add the drivers repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
- Next `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` or you can install from 'Additional Drivers'
- Install recommended driver, reboot
- `nvidia-smi` should be showing process and `nvidia-settings` will be launching NVIDIA profile

References:

- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-with-rtx-3070-on-ryzen-5900-black-screen-after-boot/167681/30
- [https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/01/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-linux/#:~:text=Install%20Nvidia%20Driver%20in%20Ubuntu%20Linux%201%20GUI,Open%20the%20application%20Nvidia%20X%20Server%20Settings.%20](https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/01/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-linux/#:%7E:text=Install%20Nvidia%20Driver%20in%20Ubuntu%20Linux%201%20GUI,Open%20the%20application%20Nvidia%20X%20Server%20Settings.%20)
- https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Comment: Yes, even I faced issues on my acer aspire 7. Brightness control wasn't working, Tried many distro like ubuntu, linux mint. Finally i upgraded to 5.11 kernel from default 5.4.x, and it worked. But still my laptop freezes randomly on Linux Mint especially after waking up from stand by.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 on a Ryzen 9 5900x and Asus tuf x570plus with zero major issues so far.  I've ran some light video encoding and am very happy with it. Only issue I'm working on is it fails to come out of suspend.  Could be a video card issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have brand new HP Zhan (hp probook 445 g8) with AMD Ryzen 5800u. I found some issues:

**Things are NOT working:**

- Screen brightness is not adjustable (always 100%) it's crazy because the
  laptop has 400 nits screen brightness.
- Cannot connect to other display via USB-C port.
- HDMI port doesn't work

**Things are working:**

- Microphone works but mute key doesn't work
- Webcam works
- Wifi works
- Bluetooth works
- Volume keys (mute, -, +) works

Hopefully they will work well with ubuntu 21.04

Comment: I tried to install 5.11.6 kernel but the problem persists.

Comment: Actually HDMI might work if you plug it first and then turn on the computer. This is the case with my 5900HX + RTX 3070 Clevo-based laptop on Ubuntu 21.04, 5.11 kernel and Nvidia driver 465.

I've got the same issue with brightness. UCB-C display not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I had exact same problems as @minh-nguyen with my AMD Ryzen 5500u. And all of them vanished once I installed ubuntu 21.04. Since I am new to ubuntu I did not want to move to non-LTS version, but i read somewhere that kernel 5.10 and higher versions have better connection to amd stuff, so I did what I did.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is lenovo IdeaPad slim 5 Pro with Ryzen 7 5800H and RTX 3050. I found a major issue when running VSCode, if I open a file that have more than 1000 lines of code the program are very laggy (I mean its unusable).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227759)